# Getting rid of $http service invoke from hand in angularjs code

Tags: angularjs, websocket

I have $http service used many times in my code. I don't like it, because I'm thinking to switch to websockets in the future, so I need some general inerface for my communication. Is any patter for some kind of communication facade in angular js? Where I could switch the communication method in one place easily and smoothly?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to create a `service` for wrapping the communication:

```
mainModule.factory("serverCommunication", function($q){

    return function(message) {

        // here goes the logic of communication

        // switch by message.type to handle the communication properly

        // should return a promise (exactly as '$http' does)
    }

})
```

where `message` could contain all information e.g.:

```
message = {
    url : 'url',
    data : {...},
    type : 'type',
    parameters : {...}
    ...
}
```

Comment: I like it, I gave +, I've been thinking about something like this too. I've been just pondering if any general commonly used sollution already exists. Thank for you input artur